# WPF updating the UI with a certain delay

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a slideshow application where i want to wait a certain amount of seconds, then show my front page, then wait again, then show next page, and so on. My problem is that when i use Thread.Sleep in between, the UI arent updated, it just sits there waiting and i only see my last control (after the full amount of time has passed (i.e all the sleeps). Any solutions for doing this?

```
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ChangeContent(new FrontPage());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            ChangeContent(new HtmlPage());
```

Pre WPF i would just use the Application.DoEvents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).